# Check if TypeElement is Kotlin Data Class in annotation processor

Tags: kotlin, annotations

I'm producing an annotation processor, with an annotation with KClass in parameters. I need to check if the KClasses I retrieve in the processor are Data Class.

I can't use

```
MyDataClass::class.isData
```

because of the `MirroredTypeException` that is thrown when you want to access to a Class or KClass parameter in an annotation, with

```
try {
    element.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation::class.java).myClass
} catch (mte: MirroredTypeException) {
    typeElement = typeUtils.asElement(mte.typeMirror) as TypeElement
}
```

Now I can only work with a TypeElement.

Kotlinpoet offers `KModifier` that contain `DATA` attribute, but it's only usable for class generation and not reading.

How can I effectively check it ?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more? Are you trying to get the class from the element?

Comment: I just want to do a check, like `if(class.isData) {...}`. I don't want to get the class itself. I just don't know what to use to do the check.

Comment: can you try this? ```element.javaClass.kotlin.isData```

Comment: Thanks. I tried, it always returns false, data class or not, so it doesn't work.

Comment: I just realized that you cannot access the class during annotation processing because they are not yet loaded, let alone compiled. You can only work with element and typeelements during processing. And I'm afraid it only describes java classes.

Comment: I see. Thank you !

Comment: @tompee I think this should be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's still relevant to you but I'll answer anyway:

In contrast to what some of the comments said, it is actually possible to find out Kotlin-specific information about elements during annotation processing, albeit a bit complicated. The additional Kotlin data is stored in protocol buffers in a `@Metadata`-annotation. You can use [this library](https://github.com/Takhion/kotlin-metadata) to read the `@Metadata`-annotations and then check them as following:

```
(element.kotlinMetadata as KotlinClassMetadata).data.classProto.isDataClass
```